# Understanding of working of Turing Machine for $\{0^k1^k\}$

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

I try to learn Computation Complexity by Sipser's textbook "Introduction to the Theory of Computation".

The problem is I have a lack in understanding how Turing Machine is working. Example from the textbook.

Let's analyze the algorithm we gave for the language $A=\{0^k1^k | k \geq 0\}$. We repeat the algorithm here for convenience.

$M_1$="On input string w:

1. Scan across the tape and reject if a 0 is found to the right of a
2. Repeat if both 0s and 1s remain on the tape.
3. Scan across the tape, crossing off a single 0 and a single 1.
4. If 0s still remain after all the 1s have been crossed off, or if 1s still remain after all the 0s have been crossed off, *reject*. Otherwise, if neither 0s nor 1s remain on the tape, *accept*."

The question is why do we need to *repeat* before each *crossing*, why we cannot just cross over all 0s and all 1s one by one in $O(n)$ and  continue to the step 4. According to the textbook each scan uses $O(n)$ steps and each scans occur $n/2$ times. So if each scan occurs $n/2$, on every step is should cross over 2 symbols: one 1 and one 0, which is can be done in linear time, so where $O(n)$ comes from? In result, the following algorithm runs in $O(n^2)$.

An improvement that comes later suggest to crossing over two 1s and 0s on every step that improves the running time to $O(nlogn)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his first example, Sipser gives a particular decision algorithm for the language $A$. He then analyzes it and finds that it runs in $O(n^2)$ steps, where $n$ is the length of the input string. This is because his algorithm will take $O(n)$ steps for each full scan and since each scan will cross off 2 symbols, we'll be done after $n/2$ scans, giving us a running time of $(n/2)O(n)=O(n^2)$ steps, showing that $A\in\text{ TIME }(n^2)$. In other words, his particular TM demonstrates that $A$ can be decided in time no worse than a fixed multiple of $n^2$.

Here's an example, with input $0011$:

- Step 1: scan all four cells. Input is the right form, so continue.
- Loop test: Scan all four cells, to determine that some zeros and ones remain.
- First iteration through the loop: scan all four cells, crossing off a 1 and a 0, giving us the tape $0X1X$.
- Loop test: Scan all four cells, to determine that some zeros and ones remain.
- Second iteration through the loop: scan all four cells, crossing off a 1 and a 0, giving us the tape $XXXX$.
- Loop test: Scan all four cells, to determine that some zeros and ones remain. Nope, so accept.

We did two ($=n/2$) loop iterations, each involving two scans of the entire tape ($n$). In general, we'll take $O(n^2)$ steps

Your idea, that we cross off all the zeros and ones in one step, is a good one, but in order to do that we'd need to keep a count of the number of zeros and ones we crossed off, otherwise we've lost any information about how many zeros/ones there are as soon as we complete the first pass. Keeping this count is indeed possible, if we use a two-tape model, and this is exactly what Sipser does in his third algorithm, a couple of pages later, where he demonstrates that $A\in\text{ TIME }(n)$.

As an aside, it's easy to see that we can't do any better than $O(n)$, since it'll take that many steps just to look at each cell in the input. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It helped me a lot.